# How to find correct min / max values of a list in Perl 6

Tags: raku

New to Perl6, trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong here. The problem is a simple checksum that takes the difference of the max and min values for each row in the [csv](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jakewmeyer/Advent-of-Code-2017/master/Day2/input.csv)

The max and min values it returns are completely wrong. For the first row in the [csv](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jakewmeyer/Advent-of-Code-2017/master/Day2/input.csv), it returns the max as 71, and the min as 104, which is incorrect.

Here's the [link](https://github.com/jakewmeyer/Advent-of-Code-2017) to the repo for reference, and the [link](https://adventofcode.com/2017/day/2) to the corresponding problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6

use Text::CSV;

sub checksum {
    my $sum = 0;
    my @data = csv(in => "input.csv");
    for @data -> @value {
        $sum += (max @value) - (min @value);
    }
    say $sum;
}

checksum
```

Comment: untested: `sub checksum($in) { [+] (+<<csv :$in).map(*.minmax.bounds.reduce(&[R-])) }; say checksum 'input.csv'`

Comment: Hello fellow AoC coder!  You may want to visit the [subreddit for AoC](https://www.reddit.com/r/adventofcode/), specifically the solution megathreads.  There are several people in there (including yours truly) posting Perl 6 solutions; you might pick up some tips there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I assume your input contains numbers, but since CSV is a text format, the input is being read in as strings. `min` and `max` are operating based on string sorting, so `max("4", "10")` is `4` but `max("04", "10")` is `10`. To solve this, you can either cast each element to `Numeric` (int, floating point, etc.) before you get the min/max:

```
@input.map(*.Numeric).max
```

or pass a conversion function to `min` and `max` so each element is parsed as a number as it's compared:

```
@input.max(*.Numeric)
```

The first solution is better for your case, since the second solution is an ephemeral conversion, converting internally but still returning a string. Final note: in normal code I would write `+*` or `{ +$_ }` to mean "treat X as a number", but in this case I prefer being explicit: `.Numeric`.

Comment: I would use `+*` (`*.Numeric`) instead of `{.Int}` (or `*.Int`) so that it will continue to work properly if fractional values are given instead.

Comment: @BradGilbert You're quite right, I've made the change. Thanks!